# C# Get and Private Set vs Get returning Private Field

Tags: c#

I asked myself for quite a while what advantages and disadvantages there are to using a property with the modifiers get and private set versus having a property that returns a private field.

Here's an example:

```
public bool Example { get; private set; }
```

and

```
private bool example;
public bool Example { get { return example; } }
```

What are the disadvantages and advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: I think at compile time, the difference between the two goes away. The `get; private set;` is just syntax sugar, just a coding shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 less line of code. Other than that, they are the exact same functionality wise. It is syntactic sugar essentially.

Comment: ...and the second example is fully _read-only_ property while the 1st AIP have a private setter.

Comment: Not really since you still have access to the variable member. A truly read-only property would have no set and can be initialize only at construction.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things, even though it's a syntax sugar with auto get set, in my opinion it depends on the design

```
public bool Example { get;  set; }
```

The above line will have a private back field created by compiler which we don't have access. But if create a backing field we will have access of it and we can use it for null check like the below one

```
private bool example;
public bool Example 
{ 
get
{
  return example;
}
set
{
     if(value != example)
     {
       example = value;
       // here you can write some property change notifications or some other logic. 
     }
} 
}
```

Either way end result is same